# Do I still need OAuth or API Key with HTTPS for Restful webservice

Tags: security, oauth, https, api-key

I am creating an application and native apps which shall access a bunch of RestFul Webservices. We are already using HTTPS to secure the API, but wanted to understand if we still need something like an API Key or OAuth Key to authenticate the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encryption and Authentication are two separate things.  Encryption merely prevents outside parties from snooping the transmitted data.  You need Authentication if you want to control who has access to which resources using the API.

Comment: Hello Remy,Thanks for your response.Can you please help me can someone sniff over my HTTPS requests made from my android app. I mean is there some way which can read the API requests made from my application. And if so, what should be a way to prevent them

Comment: Again, encryption prevents snooping.  So no, an outside party cannot sniff the requests if they are encrypted.  However, it is possible for a Man-in-the-middle attacker to intercept the requests unless you use certificates to have the client and server validate each other's identity.